# Python Selenium edit text content of specific javascript element in specific iframe

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to use python selenium to change the text in a specific JS element. 
I started out by attempting to simply execute the script using the following:

`driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#cssSelector').textContent='{}'".format(text))`

However, unfortunately, this returns null

When looking into the JS the selector is in a specific iframe so I have tried to select the iframe but this has not yet worked:

```
driver.execute_script('''var element=window.frames['iframe'].document.querySelector("[id='cssselector']"); element.textContent='{}'".format(text))
```

This code also returns undefined as it cannot find the element.

Is there a better way to do this? thanks

Comment: Post your HTML or a link to the page you are automating. It is basically impossible to help you without that information. The first issue I see has to do with your quotations in your `execute_script` block -- wrap the whole script in `"` quotations (`"var element=..."`), and use single quotations like `'` to quote items inside the script such as `'iframe'`.

Comment: I am looking at Yahoo Recaptcha challenge. Trying to automate some email stuff but just need to input 2captcha token into Recaptcha but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I don’t think captcha can be automated. That’s why captcha is used to stop bots or any automated tool.

Comment: the <iframe> is basically another window, so you have to switch the driver to it in order to access the elements.  Use a webdriver wait along with this expected condition to switch:  https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-org.openqa.selenium.By-  However, Muzzamil is right... the captcha will likely just force you to solve it over and over and never pass.

Comment: I've been looking at this other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688300/2captcha-api-selenium) and it seems to just be using javascript to send the ReCaptcha token